# No Hyper-v for windows home edition? Can i still install Oracle virtual box?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, bios

I have Windows 10 Home on my HP laptop. I want to install oracle virtualbox with SAS university Edition. I was wondering if that is possible?

I installed Oracle virtual box with sas university edition.When I start the app it gives me following error :-

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine SAS University Edition.

VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).
```

I ran the processor identity tool and this is the output.

> ```
> Enhanced Halt State: Yes
>
> Execute Disable Bit: Yes
>
> Intel(R) Hyper-Threading Technology: Yes
>
> Intel(R) 64 Architecture: Yes
>
> (Intel(R) Virtualization Technology: Yes
>
> Intel(R) VT-x with Extended Page Tables: Yes)
> ```

I am not sure if that shows that vt-x is enabled or not.

I was wondering if somebody can help me with BIOS setting too.
I press `DEL` but it doesnot show any options to change the settings.

Answer (score 0):

From the processor identity tool, it appears that your processor supports virtualization, but from the error in Virtual Box, it's not turned on. Out of the box, this feature is turned off for most computers.

You will need to go into the BIOS to turn this on. It's tucked away in the security section most likely for an HP BIOS, then under the System Security option.

Here's a forum post that has some screenshots of where it should be. If you can't find it, just poke around until you find the options that state something about vt-x or virtualization as BIOS menus will vary.

http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/How-to-Enable-Intel-Virtualization-Technology-vt-x-on-HP/td-p/3198063

Comment: Thank you TheGrandPackard for the very informative link and  the explanation of the error.